# not able to remove the previous data in list view in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

Objective of the below code :
To return the data based on the filters applied in the search query.

Issue :
Even though after applying the filters and the correct data being received the filtered data is added on the existing data present in the list view.
So for example :
If on opening the page first time 10 count of data is loaded but incase after applying the filters and getting 5 count of data the total number of count is showing as 15 whereas I want only the filtered data to be present.

Therefore after applying the filters only 5 count should be shown in the list view.

I have tried .clear() in multiple location with set state but not able to clear the List before the next data is loaded.

Hence if you could please help me to resolve this issue at the earliest.

Let me know if additional information is required.

Thank you.

Search,dart

```
//filters is shown in the modelbottomsheet below 
void _addFilter(BuildContext ctx) {
    final notificationData =
        Provider.of<FilterOptionProvider>(context, listen: false);
    final ndata = notificationData.items;

    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: ctx,
        builder: (_) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 40,
                child: TextButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                  //textColor: Colors.black,
                  child: const Text(
                    'Apply',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                        color: Colors.black87,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  onPressed: _apply,
                ),
              ),

//Is called after the user clicks on the apply button above
void _apply() {
    audmin = amin.text;
    audmax = amax.text;
    if (audmin.isNotEmpty && audmax.isNotEmpty) {
      String audAge = audmin + ';' + audmax;
      checkfilters["audienceAge"] = audAge;
    }
Provider.of<FilterOptionProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .readfilters(checkfilters);

      Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

Comment: Provider.of<FilterOptionProvider>(context, listen: true)
          .readfilters(checkfilters);

Comment: Hi it is throwing an error that listen should be false